# SSL error in testng framewrok

Tags: java, ssl, testng, github-api

I'm connecting to Github API via Testing framework, while it tying to connect following endpoint (any endpoint in api.github.com) it will give following error:

> https://api.github.com/repos/myrepo/Test/git/blobs/929246f65aab4d636cb229c790f966afc332c124

```
FAILED: testGetBlobWithMandatoryParameters
         github {getBlob} integration test with mandatory parameters.
javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target.
```

This connection is working if i use normal java client, problem occurring only when i connect via testing framework.

My code:

```
@Test(priority = 1, description = "github {getBlob} integration test.")
    public void testGetBlobWithMandatoryParameters() throws IOException, JSONException{
            String urlStr = "https://api.github.com/repos/myrepo/Test/git/blobs/929246f65aab4d636cb229c790f966afc332c124";

    URL url = new URL(urlStr);
    HttpURLConnection httpConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();

    httpConnection.setRequestMethod("GET");
    InputStream responseStream = null;
    String responseString = null;

    if (httpConnection.getResponseCode() >= 400) {
        responseStream = httpConnection.getErrorStream();
    } else {
        responseStream = httpConnection.getInputStream();
    }



    if (responseStream != null) {

        StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
        byte[] bytes = new byte[1024];
        int len;

        while ((len = responseStream.read(bytes)) != -1) {
            stringBuilder.append(new String(bytes, 0, len));

        }

        if (!stringBuilder.toString().trim().isEmpty()) {
            responseString = stringBuilder.toString();
        }            
    }       
    System.out.println(responseString);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

add

```
 System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.trustStore", "keystore.jks")
System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.trustStorePassword", "changeit")
```